# ParseRole Basics Android

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I'm making an app and if I want to have a class called Student with certain attributes only belonging to Student (i.e grades), then Teacher with unique attributes only belong to teachers (i.e subjects taught). Is using ParseRole the best way to achieve this, keeping in mind that both Students and Teachers are both Users of the app and can log in?.

Also, I was consulting the Parse Docs and I came across setting Read and Write Permissions (ACLs) for a specific ParseRoles. If I wanted Students to be able to modify their own attributes like let say enroll in more classes (add to some List object in their schema) would I need to enable RW permissions, or does RW permissions refer to like modifying other roles not just one's own attributes.

I just need some clarification on how to best to implement this,

Thanks.

Comment: I'd create a separate class for Student and another one for Teacher. On your User class, you can have a pointer to the associated Student and a pointer to the associated Teacher. You can set ACL on Student objects to only allow write permission to the associated User. Same thing for Teacher.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo That's basically what I ended up doing, I just had an attribute on the User class that pointed to a student in the Student table or teacher in the Teacher table depending if the User was a student or teacher.